# Page Doesn't show content on FIREFOX, but does in Chrome, and even IE

Tags: html, css, firefox, background, css-float

Strangely certain aspects of one of my page doesn't show on FireFox. I have narrowed the problem down to this:

Main Page (Works On All Browsers) 
The `<div id="wrapper">` has the following CSS:

```
margin: 0px auto;
width: 1000px;
background-color: #272727;
min-height: 100%; /* ie6 ignores min-height completely */
height: 100%;
background-size:100%;
```

This ensures the nice grayish background. Also I am using the masonary jquery script for floating all my stuff. At the end of all my floats I clear them with :

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

This makes everything perfect. However on another page, that didn't seem to work so instead I added this line of code to the wrapper style (for that page)

```
style="overflow: auto;"
```

Now on IE and Chrome that's all good and well, and restores the background, but on firefox neither the content or the background is to be seen. On removing the code, the content is there but the background is not.

Why is this? What surprised me most is that IE worked and firefox didn't?!

Comment: www.carsmart.org.uk/New is the working page

www.carsmart.org.uk/New/selection.php is broken

Comment: It is due to the tagbar `<div>` above the wrapper `<div>` is floating left, So you need to clear the floating. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

Add `clear:both` or `clear:left` and `overflow:auto;` in the **wrapper** css.

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #272727;
    background-size: 100% auto;        
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
    clear: both; /* Added Clear Property */
    overflow:auto; /* Added Overflow Property */
}
```

Because **tagbar** `<div>` above the **wrapper** `<div>` is floating left, So you need to clear the floating.

http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/3145/imgej.png

Comment: But then the background is gone?

Comment: @Mombassa: Don't remove `overflow:auto` it will stay there. Also updated my answer with an addition of `overflow:auto` in `wrapper`

Comment: Sorry was busy, I couldn't accept the answer as was busy. Massive help thank you.